How to print only specified controls from a column, in a Python3 script using Flet?
In a Python3-Flet script I have a Column, with various controls (Dropdown, Textfields, Button) and I need to print only TextFields's values.
This is my script:
from flet import *
def main(page:Page):
    def print_only_textfields(e):
        for textfield in column.controls:print(textfield)
    column=Column(controls=[Dropdown(value='dropdown'),
                            TextField(value='text1'),
                            TextField(value='text2'),
                            ElevatedButton('PRINT',on_click=print_only_textfields)])
    page.add(column)
app(target=main)

This is what I get:
dropdown {'value': 'dropdown'}
textfield {'value': 'text1'}
textfield {'value': 'text2'}
elevatedbutton {'text': 'PRINT'}

This is what I want to get:
textfield {'value': 'text1'}
textfield {'value': 'text2'}


just solved by myself: if textfield._get_control_name()=='textfield':print(textfield)
